# What does a function $f(x_0)$ represent if we substitute the x value from $f'(x) = 0$ into $f(x)$?

Tags: calculus

For the given functions $f(x) = e^x - \ln(x)$ and its derivative $f'(x) = e^x - \frac 1x$. Finding the local minimum wouldn't be possible because of the presence of both an exponential and a polynomial term. But we can find an approximation of the coordinates.

Since we are focused on the coordinates of the minimum, we can also say that the minimum lies on the function $f(x_0) = e^{x_0} - \ln(x_0)$ where $x_0$ is the x-coordinate of the minimum. I noticed the following, if we know that minimum occurs at $e^x - \frac 1x = 0$, we can rewrite this as $e^x=\frac 1x$ where x = $x_0$. This results $e^{x_0}=\frac 1{x_0}$. Substituting this into our original function, gives us $f(x_0) = \frac 1{x_0} - \ln(x_0)$. To find a substitution for $\ln(x)$ we can take the ln of both side of the equation $e^{x_0} = \frac 1{x_0}$, which results in $\ln(e^{x_0}) = -\ln(x_0)$. This simplifies to $-\ln(x_0) = x_0$. Therefore, our final function is $f(x_0) = x_0 + \frac 1{x_0}$.

When graphing the function $f(x) = e^x - \ln(x)$ we can see that its minimum is definitely greater than $y = 2$. So we can then write the inequality $x_0 + \frac 1{x_0} > 2$. Solving this results $x>1 \land 0<x<1$. Substitute x = 1 into $f'(x)$ gives $e-1$ as solution. Substitute $x = \frac{1}{2}$ into $f'(x)$ gives $\sqrt{e}-2$ as solution. $e-1>0$ and $\sqrt{e}-2<0$ which means that the minimum is within the interval $[0,1]$ or even more accurate within $[\frac{1}{2},1]$. Substituting $x = 1$ into $f(x)$ yields $e$. It's not very close to the actual coordinates, but it's getting there.

To make sure that this actually works, we can try to use another y-coordinate like $\frac{13}{6}$. Giving us the inequality $x_0+\frac 1{x_0}>\frac{13}{6}$. Solving this inequality will give use $x<\frac{2}{3} \land x>\frac{3}{2}$. Since we have used $x = 1$ and $\frac{3}{2} > 1$ we only want to use $x=\frac{2}{3}$. And again substituting this value into $f'(x)$ will give us $e^{\frac{2}{3}}+\frac{3}{2}$, which is greater than zero. And substituting the solution into $f(x)$ yields $y = e^{\frac{2}{3}}-\ln({\frac{2}{3}})$. This is indeed closer to the real minimum.

This illustrates how simplifying the function from $f(x) = e^x - \ln(x)$ to $f(x_0) = x_0 + \frac{1}{x_0}$ enables us to find an approximate solution for the minimum. But I've a question regarding this $f(x_0) = x_0 + \frac 1{x_0}$. Why is it possible to use this function in inequalities? And why does this function have a local minimum at $x = 1$ and not the actual minimum value? Although $f(x_0)$ has different values, it also has similar characteristics to the original function $f(x)$, what is the reason for this?